# Angular 2 get filename from file download

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't seem to get the content-disposition header to show up. I can only see Content-Type. It's in my response though.

```
public openAttachment(id: number) {
this.http
  .get(`${this.startupService.baseUrl}company/${this.company.companyID}/attachment/${id}`,
     {responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);

    const contentDis = data.headers.get('content-disposition');
    console.log(contentDis);

    const contentType = data.headers.get('content-type');
    console.log(contentType);
  });
}
```

Here's a copy of my console log:

[image]

and here's the response:

[image]

Comment: my workaround right now is to properly set the mime type on the server. Angular detects this and opens the file appropriately, however the filename is a guid instead of the original filename.

Answer (score 3):

It didn't seem to be the fault of your code.

If 'Access-Control-Expose-Header' is not correctly set in your backend, browser client code cannot access it.

So, check and set `Access-Control-Expose-Headers(‘Content-Disposition’)`  in your backend code.

https://jaketrent.com/post/expose-http-headers-in-cors/ link might be helpful in this case.

Comment: The header is being sent. You can see that in the image at the bottom of my post

Comment: Javascript code cannot access it before CORS allowed.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 2):

In service.ts

```
  bulkValidations(id){
    let url = `exportForValidation/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
      .map((res: Response) => res)
      .catch((error: Response | any) => {
        return Observable.throw(error);
      });
  }
```

In .ts file

```
  this.employeeService.bulkValidations(this.id).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {      
          let filename = data.headers.get('content-disposition').split(';')[1].split('=')[1].replace(/\"/g, '')
        }));
```

this single line help me to get the filename from response header.

```
let filename = data.headers.get('content-disposition').split(';')[1].split('=')[1].replace(/\"/g, '')
```

Comment: Excellent.worked like a charm.